# Rotation animation is not working in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to rotate an `UIImageView`, it works in iOS8 but not in iOS7. Here's the code, I'm doing,

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [self createAnimation];
}



- (void)animationStart {
    [self.animationImageView.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
}



- (void)animationStop {
    [self.animationImageView.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
}



- (void)createAnimation {
    rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: -M_PI * 2.0 ];
    rotationAnimation.duration = 0.7;
    rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
    rotationAnimation.repeatCount = CGFLOAT_MAX;
}
```

Comment: What does "invalid" mean?

Comment: thx for answer ,"invalid" means The imageView which I add the animation can't rotate.

Answer (score 0):

use this code to image rotate,

```
- (void)startSpinImage
{
    if ([_img.layer animationForKey:@"SpinAnimation"] == nil)
    {
        CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
        animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
        animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 2*M_PI];
        animation.duration = 10.0f;
        animation.repeatCount = INFINITY;
        [_img.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SpinAnimation"];
    }
}

- (void)stopSpinImage
{
    [_img.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"SpinAnimation"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
[animationImageView startAnimating];
[animationImageView stopAnimating];
```